# How to convert isodate to utc in talend

Tags: talend

I am getting
"Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main".In talend for version 6.2.2 in big data while trying to convert string which is formatted in UTC time format ,And the error occurred during the conversion of UTC string to long .

Comment: show code or components you are using.

Comment: Mysql----->tjavaflex--->tMemorizeRows_1--->tmap_1>tjavaflex_2>tlogrow